# How to resolve issue with google.apis.core Could not install Google.Apis.Core 1.8.2 Install this package targets 'WindowsPhoneApp,Version=v8.1',

Tags: .net, visual-studio, google-api, windows-phone-8.1, nuget-package

Trying to install the google.api.core from NuGet. I have the Update2 for Visual Studio 2013 and I have the newest version of NuGet and getting the following error:

Attempting to resolve dependency 'Google.Apis.Core (≥ 1.8.2)'. 
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Newtonsoft.Json (≥ 5.0.5)'. 
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Bcl (≥ 1.0.19)'. 
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Bcl.Build (≥ 1.0.14)'. 
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Bcl.Async (≥ 1.0.16)'. 
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Net.Http (≥ 2.1.10)'. 
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Zlib.Portable (≥ 1.9.2)'. 
Installing 'Zlib.Portable 1.9.2'. 
Successfully installed 'Zlib.Portable 1.9.2'. 
Installing 'Google.Apis.Core 1.8.2'. 
Successfully installed 'Google.Apis.Core 1.8.2'. 
Installing 'Google.Apis 1.8.2'. 
Successfully installed 'Google.Apis 1.8.2'. 
Adding 'Zlib.Portable 1.9.2' to XXXXX. 
Uninstalling 'Zlib.Portable 1.9.2'. 
Successfully uninstalled 'Zlib.Portable 1.9.2'. 
Install failed. Rolling back...
Could not install package 'Zlib.Portable 1.9.2'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'WindowsPhoneApp,Version=v8.1', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

SOLVED the zip, well AdvancedREI did:

https://twitter.com/AdvancedREI/status/483688601872760832

Zlib.Portable 1.10 has been released! Support for Windows Phone 8.1 & Universal apps, plus Xamarin & bug fixes!

Now I am getting Could not install package 'Google.Apis.Core 1.8.2'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'WindowsPhoneApp,Version=v8.1',

Comment: According to the error message the library `Zlib.Portable 1.9.2` does not support your projects target which is `WindowsPhoneApp,Version=v8.1`. So there is no way to install `Google.Apis.Core` into that project because it depends on the above mentioned package. There is an [open issue](https://github.com/advancedrei/Zlib.Portable/pull/4) for the Windows Phone 8.1 support on the project github repo.

Comment: Zlib.Portable updated, now the google.api needs to be updated...

Comment: Yeah, I have notified the developer at Google. Hopefully they will fix it soon.

Answer (score 2):

https://twitter.com/AdvancedREI/status/483688601872760832

Zlib.Portable 1.10 has been released! Support for Windows Phone 8.1 & Universal apps, plus Xamarin & bug fixes!

BUt now I am getting Could not install package 'Google.Apis.Core 1.8.2'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'WindowsPhoneApp,Version=v8.1',